# OnsenUI - Multiple templates in one file : templates showing at the bottom

Tags: angularjs, cordova, templates, onsen-ui

I'm developing a mobile app with cordova and onsenui.
I have a issue with [defining multiple pages in single HTML](http://onsen.io/guide/overview.html#DefiningMultiplePagesinSingleHTML).

Here's my HTML :

```
<ons-page ng-controller="accountController">
<ons-tabbar>
    <ons-tab page="profile.html" label="Profil" icon="ion-person" active="true"></ons-tab>
    <ons-tab page="filters.html" label="Filtres" icon="ion-android-options"></ons-tab>
    <ons-tab page="settings.html" label="Paramètres" icon="ion-gear-a"></ons-tab>
</ons-tabbar>
</ons-page>


<ons-template id="profile.html">
<ons-toolbar>
    <div class="left">
        <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="menu.toggle()">
            <ons-icon icon="ion-navicon" size="28px" fixed-width="false"></ons-icon>
        </ons-toolbar-button>
    </div>
    <div class="center">Mon profil</div>
    <div class="right">
        <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="saveAccount()">
            <ons-icon icon="ion-android-done" size="28px" fixed-width="false"></ons-icon>
        </ons-toolbar-button>
    </div>
</ons-toolbar>
<ons-list>
    <ons-list-item>
        <ons-row>
            <ons-col size="30%">
                <img src="res/dev/person.png" style="max-height: inherit; max-width: inherit;" />
            </ons-col>
            <ons-col size="70%">
                <label>{{ data.shortname }}</label>
            </ons-col>
        </ons-row>
    </ons-list-item>
    <ons-list-item>
        <input type="text" ng-model="data.firstname" placeholder="Prénom"
               class="text-input text-input--transparent"
               style="margin-top:8px; width: 100%;"
               autocapitalize="on" autocomplete="on"
               spellcheck="false" autocorrect="off" cb-before="Prénom" />
    </ons-list-item>
    <ons-list-item>
        <input type="text" ng-model="data.lastname" placeholder="Nom de famille"
               class="text-input text-input--transparent"
               style="margin-top:8px; width: 100%;"
               autocapitalize="on" autocomplete="on"
               spellcheck="false" autocorrect="off" cb-before="Nom de famille"/>
    </ons-list-item>
</ons-list>
</ons-template>

<ons-template id="filters.html">
<ons-toolbar>
    <div class="left">
        <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="menu.toggle()">
            <ons-icon icon="ion-navicon" size="28px" fixed-width="false"></ons-icon>
        </ons-toolbar-button>
    </div>
    <div class="center">Mes filtres</div>
    <div class="right">
        <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="saveAccount()">
            <ons-icon icon="ion-android-done" size="28px" fixed-width="false"></ons-icon>
        </ons-toolbar-button>
    </div>
</ons-toolbar>
<ons-list>
    <ons-list-item>
        Filtres
    </ons-list-item>
</ons-list>
</ons-template>

<ons-template id="settings.html">
<ons-toolbar>
    <div class="left">
        <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="menu.toggle()">
            <ons-icon icon="ion-navicon" size="28px" fixed-width="false"></ons-icon>
        </ons-toolbar-button>
    </div>
    <div class="center">Paramètres</div>
    <div class="right">
        <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="saveAccount()">
            <ons-icon icon="ion-android-done" size="28px" fixed-width="false"></ons-icon>
        </ons-toolbar-button>
    </div>
</ons-toolbar>
<ons-list>
    <ons-list-item>
        Email : {{ data.email }}
    </ons-list-item>

    <ons-list-item>
        <input type="text" ng-model="data.pwd" placeholder="Mot de passe" class="text-input text-input--transparent" style="margin-top:8px; width: 100%;">
    </ons-list-item>
</ons-list>
</ons-template>
```

So the objective here is to have a tab page, with 3 tabs.
It's working, but the templates still displaying at the bottom of the page, not rendered :

[image: Templates showing at the bottom, not rendered]

I found out that I can use `<script type="text/ons-template" id="profile.html">` in place of `<ons-template id="profile.html">`, but then I get an error saying that it cannot find the template.

I also found out that I can use `<script type="text/ng-template" (...)>`. **That's working**.

Also, I could just define each template in a separate file, but then I'd be having a LOT of files (it's not the only file where I get that problem).

So my questions are : am I doing it wrong ? Is there anybody out there who had the same problem, and solved it ?

Thanks for your help ;)

Comment: `<ons-tab page="profile.html">` requires and `<ons-page>`. You cannot put `<ons-toolbar>` directly in `<ons-template>`, You need to wrap it within `<ons-page>`

For example:
`<ons-template id="profile.html">
<ons-page>
<ons-toolbar></ons-toolbar>
...
</ons-page>
</ons-template>

Comment: Thanks for your help !
Since then I've changed my code a lot and the framework was upgraded too, so now it works fine. But I'll look again at my code and see if putting a page into the templates works as well.

Comment: it should work, as long as you it followed `<ons-template>` guidlines for page:
`<ons-template>`
<ons-page>
<!-- page content here -->
</ons-page>
</ons-template>`